# String literal as argument in QT

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

I have found this **class constructor**:

```
classname::classname(int x, Qstring url):
  x(2),
  url("www.nameclient.se"),
  clientversion("??")

  {

  }
```

what does the question mark("**??**") in clientversion("??") means?
Clientversion is a member of the class of type    Qstring.
I 'm asking about the semantic of the qestion mark.

Comment: nobody can tell as long as nobody knows what `clientversion` is and how it is implemented...

Comment: it is a member variable of the class of type Qstring, i just want to understand how does the question mark work?

Comment: Best to search the classname.cpp for occurrences of `clientversion` and see where it's compared to `"??"`.

Comment: when i work with sql  "*" means any string inside the quotation, but when i use "?" means an litter or digit inside the quotation. but in c++ i have searched and found nothing explains this

Comment: To me it looks like poor default values (both for clientversion and especially url)

Answer (score 3):

There is no special semantics to the question marks as far as `QString` or C++ are concerned. It's just a string literal, so the `clientversion` is initialized to exactly that: two question marks. As for its meaning for this class, one has either to guess or to look at the sources. I'd guess that it probably means that the client version is unknown.

Comment: @SergyTachenov i agree with your answer, although no place in the text interpret this string literal, so i will consdier as unkown client version